# Lifting automorphisms of a curve to its symmetric square and Jacobian

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Say I have a curve $C$ (a smooth projective plane quartic), defined over a field $K$, with a model of the form $Y^3Z = f(X,Z)$, with $f(X,Z)\in K[X,Z]$ a homogeneous polynomial of degree $4$.

The curve $C$ has a non-trivial automorphism $[\omega]$, where $\omega$ is a non-trivial cube root of unity. $[\omega]$ acts on a point $(x,y,z)$ via:

$$[\omega](x,y,z) = (x,\omega y, z).$$

By functoriality of the symmetric square, and Jacobian, the order $3$ automorphism group $\Gamma$ generated by $[\omega]$ lifts to give automorphisms of both the symmetric square and the Jacobian of $C$.

My question is, is there an embedding $\phi: C^{(2)}\longrightarrow J$ which is $\Gamma$-equivariant, i.e. an embedding $\phi$ which satisfies for each $P\in C^{(2)}$, $\phi([\omega](P)) = [\omega](\phi(P))$.

Answer (score 1):

The morphism
$$
C^{(2)} := S^2C \to \mathrm{Pic}^2(C),
\qquad 
(P,Q) \mapsto \mathcal{O}_C(P+Q)
$$
is equivariant under the entire group of automorphisms, so if you define $J(C)$ as $\mathrm{Pic}^2(C)$, you are OK. If you want to have the target in $\mathrm{Pic}^d(C)$ for $d \ne 2$, you need to shift by an invariant line bundle of degree $d - 2$, and you can take as such, for instance, $\mathcal{O}_C((d-2)P_0)$, where $P_0 \in C$ is a fixed point of $[\omega]$.

Comment: Why is the morphism $C^{(2)}\longrightarrow \text{Pic}^2(C)$ equivariant under the entire automorphism group?

Comment: Also, say I want to define $J := \text{Pic}^0(C)$, and say I have a degree $2$ $[\omega]$ fixed point $O$, such that if $\phi: C^{(2)}\longrightarrow J$ is defined via $(P,Q)\mapsto P+Q-O$, could it not be the case that $[\omega](P+Q-O)$ would lie in a shift of the image? For example we would have some degree $0$ divisor $R$ such that $[\omega]\phi(C^{(2)}) = \phi(C^{(2)}) + R$? Perhaps implying that the morphism is not equivariant?

Comment: Just compare how $\mathrm{Aut}(C)$ acts on the source and target.